# Lazy load of non-singleton in guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, provider

I'm using Guice for DI in my project, and I want to have lazy initialization of non-singleton object in my class.
I was trying to use `Provider`, but it returned new instance every time I call `get()` method.

```
public class MyClass {
  @Inject
  private Provider<Service> serviceProvider; //Service is NOT Singleton

  public void meth1() {
    Service s1 = serviceProvider.get();       
  }

  public void meth2() {
    Service s2 = serviceProvider.get();
  }
  //I want  s1 and s2 to be the same object
}
```

Does Guice can do it, or is there any other practices to reach that?

Comment: "I want  s and s2 to be the same object" - why? If they are 2 references to the same instance then why do you need 2 references in the first place?

Comment: Why not do: `Service s2 = s;` ? and what does "lazy inject" mean?

Comment: I edit message. Hope now it's more explicit what I mean

Comment: `Suppliers.memoize(serviceProvider::get)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tavian mentioned in the comments, the best solution is `Suppliers.memoize(serviceProvider::get)`, or some equivalent. [Suppliers](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html) (and [Supplier](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html)) are in the Google utility library [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), and since Java 8, Guava's Supplier extends the Java 8 functional interface [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), though Java 8 doesn't supply a Suppliers equivalent built-in. The specification of `serviceProvider::get` is necessary to make Provider behave as a Supplier without an explicit adapter, even though they both specify exactly one method, a zero-arg `T get()`.

Unlike Google's other DI framework, [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/), Supplier doesn't have a [Lazy](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Lazy.html) class to provide the local memoization you're looking for. Though you could do the kind of "check then set" behavior that tmarwen offers in [their updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47552149/1426891), that strategy (as mentioned in their comment) is not thread-safe, while [Suppliers.memoize](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize-com.google.common.base.Supplier-) is explicitly thread-safe.

Though Guava provides a lot of useful features, you may not want to add a whole new library for a single method. If you do need the thread safety without the full library, you can take a look at [the Apache-licensed implementation here](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.java#L100).

Comment: So, Guice doesn't provide this feature from box, but it easy to use Suppliers from Guava. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need `s1` and `s2` to refer to the same instance, then you just need a single instance of `Service` for an instance of `MyClass` and which resolves simply to an *instance field*:

```
public class MyClass {

  @Inject
  private Provider<Service> serviceProvider;

  private Service service;

  public void meth1() {
    if (this.service == null) this.service = this.serviceProvider.get();
    // use service 
  }

  public void meth2() {
    if (this.service == null) this.service = this.serviceProvider.get();
    // use service 
  }
}
```

Comment: But it is not lazy initialization of Service. I want Service to be initialized only at meth1 or meth2.

Comment: I've updated the answer to match your requirement but not that this approach does not show to be the optimal one and specifically is not thread-safe.